# Predicting gamma distribution using NN, using method of moments in loss function?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, mathematical-statistics, loss-functions

I'm trying to train a neural network on a time series that would predict the gamma distribution of time between 'events' in the next hour.

I would like to do an empirical fit on the time between 'events' in order to get an **α** and **β** (parameters of the gamma dist.) that will be used as labels. My thought is that I want to have my final NN layer output two parameters **α'** and **β'** that will be used as parameters for predicted gamma distribution.

*However, I'm struggling to come up with a loss function that makes sense.*

Would using method of moments in my loss function be statistically sound? If I were to define the loss function as the squared error of the first, second, third,... moments as such:

[image]

where **α** and **β** are the label's parameters and **α'** and **β'** are the outputs from my neural net. This loss function seems a little hackey, and I'm not sure if there's a better way to define it. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks alot!